# How to split a line on Thorn character 'þ' in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, split

How to split a line on Thorn character 'þ' in linux ?

I have tried the following

```
awk -F 'þ' '{print $2}'
awk -F '\xC3\xBE\x02' '{print $2}'
awk -F 'Ã¾' '{print $2}'
```

nothing worked.

EDIT:
The file is located in HDFS(Hadoop File System) path the following command works on command line but not in shell script (when shell script is executed, it gives an empty output ie thorn char is not recognized!!

Command line:

```
~/etltestsar/DoubleClick$ hadoop fs -cat /raw/doubleclick/data/dt=2015-03-30/NetworkMatchtablesActivity_7657_03-30-2015_advertiser.log.gz|gunzip|tail -n +2|awk -F 'þ' '
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

3848762
3963771
4112862
4140939
4199580
4199584
.....
```

Same command in shell script produces no output

```
hadoop@node28-19-88:~/etltestsar/DoubleClick$ sh testthorn.sh
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
```

Comment: At a minimum post some sample input and expected output in every question.

Comment: What platform, what locale/character encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Get a different awk? GNU awk 4.1.1 in bash 4.1.17(9) on cygwin:

```
$ cat file
fooþbar

$ awk -F 'þ' '{print $2}' file
bar
```

Comment: Ed, commands works in command line and not when executed through shell. Moreover the file is in HDFS. I have edited by question

Comment: I've no idea what hadoop or a HDFS are but if you edit your question to show the script you are executing maybe someone will spot the problem. I edited your question to format what you already have correctly but part of your command line was missing. Use the editor button `{}` to format code properly.